# When sending some custom ERC-20 tokens to the other accounts, is the other accounts received fewer tokens?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat

When sending some custom ERC-20 tokens to the other accounts, is the other accounts received fewer tokens?

I send my custom ERC20 tokens to the other account on solidity 0.15 the custom tokens. (150000000000000000 Wei)

However, The other account received only 149999997646012400 Wei.

Was it works well?

I think the other account must have the same amount of custom tokens and the sender needed to pay native tokens like ETH, and BnB tokens as gas for that.

What am I getting wrong information?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I solved it. When I use a new account as the sender instead of the default signer account, It worked well. Or restarting The hardhat local network is also worked. It seems to be a bug.